# SQL many to many relationship solution: intermediate table or xml query?

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, many-to-many, relationship

I am building a video database.
And a video you knows, has many tags.And each tag also related to many videos.

The normal solution is create a intermediate table recording relationship between every tag and video.
Just now, to my surprise,I learn about mysql can query xml!So I think I can save all tags of a video to one column in the Video table.

But I wonder whether it is more efficient by this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is great for storing unstructured and structured data. MySQL is great for storing structured data. Is this data unstructured? Sound like it is a simple many to many relationship to me. XML can also be a performance killer see this [Performance of MySql Xml functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668324/performance-of-mysql-xml-functions)

This is a design decision and there is no hard and fast rule. I would suggest that you test both approaches and make a informed choice. However I have found that MySQL will perform much better in joining a many to many relationship than parsing XML.

Last time I checked you could not index the XML either. Oh and then there is one thing you got to remember. Bloat... XML documents can bloat a database. For example in a relational design you would store the tag `Kung Fu` once and then associate that tag with the right movies. In the XML approach you would store `<tag>Kung Fu</tag>` potentially thousands of time.

In your design you want to add all xml to one column? That is going to be a huge XML document and seriously kill performance at some point I am willing to bet on that. I was thinking a bit on my walk home and one of the serious consequences will be if you stuff all tags into one XML column the contention on updates and reads is also going to be huge. You will get better performance if for every movie you stored a XML column with tags in. That one column with all XML in is going to lock up like a dungeon keeper holding a princess.

So like I said each one has its cons and pros. Test them both and learn new skills.